# Signal Problem in creating instance of my model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, signals

please help
I have a problem
I'm trying to write a signal in my code when the user registers, create a portfolio and profile for the user, it can create a user and profile and portfolio correctly but when I want to create a market in admin(because only admin can create a market, not user) I got an error from my signal this line('instance.Portfolio.save()'),
My Signal

```
    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_portfolio(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Portfolio.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=Market)
def save_user_portfolio(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.Portfolio.save(market=instance)
```

And it is my portfolio model

```
    class Portfolio(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=True, default='portfolio')
    user = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='investor')
    assets = models.ManyToManyField(Assets, related_name='assets')
```

My user model

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_author = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    auth_provider = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, blank=False,
        null=False, default=AUTH_PROVIDERS.get('email'))
```

I have to say my portfolio and user are in a different app
And it's my market model maybe you need it

```
    class Market(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False, null=False)
```

My error is:
'Market' object has no attribute 'Portfolio'

Comment: Since the `instance` is a `Market` instance, it does not have an attribute `Portfolio`. You should call `instance.save()` instead of `instance.Portfolio.save()`.

Comment: I did what you said but  got a new error: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object'

Comment: I don't think you need the `post_save` signal if you are going to only call `instance.save()`. Also, the reason why the maximum recursion depth exceeded occurs is because when you call `instance.save()` inside the signal, it will also trigger the signal again and again, which results in the recursion depth exceeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved by the below code,

I needed to disconnect the signal before saving, then connect again

```
    def post_save_product(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    post_save.disconnect(post_save_product, sender=sender)
    instance.save()
    post_save.connect(post_save_product, sender=sender)
post_save.connect(post_save_product, sender= Market)
```